# What is a valid pattern for an XSD restriction consisting of an xs:float and an xs:string?

Tags: .net, xml, c#-4.0, xsd, xsd-validation

I try to validate by XSD an attribute that can contain a float type or a word "exist". After search in the net I found this [solution](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp), but it did not work when I tried this pattern:

```
<pre lang="XML">
<xs:restriction base="xs:String">
  <xs:pattern value="[0-9]| 'exist'"/>
</xs:restriction>
```

how to validate the xml file

Comment: You could use a pattern, but it would look nothing like your example. A valid pattern allowing any integer or "exist" would be `<xs:pattern value="[0-9]+|exist"/>`. But using a union type is better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an `xs:union` that allows you to specify another `xs:simpleType` in the `memberTypes` field:

```
<xs:simpleType name="existType">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:enumeration value="exist" />
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="floatType">
  <xs:union memberTypes="xs:float existType" />
</xs:simpleType>
```

Then use this `floatType` in a type definition:

```
<xs:element name="Pre" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="floatType" />
```